# How can I debug high indexing rate in AWS Elasticsearch but less docs on Kibana?

Tags: elasticsearch, aws-elasticsearch

I have an Elasticsearch cluster setup on AWS, that is setup only for viewing logs on Kibana. So, it is only taking logs from the envs which are being sent using Fluentd. I recently noticed that the indexing rate reached 10k when the logs on Kibana were not more that 1k.

AWS docs have following explanation for Indexing Rate ([link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/es-managedomains.html#es-managedomains-cloudwatchmetrics)):

```
The number of indexing operations per minute. A single call to the _bulk API 
that adds two documents and updates two counts as four operations, which might 
be spread across  one or more nodes. If that index has one or more replicas, 
other nodes in the cluster also record a total of four indexing operations.
Document deletions do not count towards this metric.
```

I want to debug how the Indexing rate reached to 10k. I tried setting up index logs for ES cluster but it is not generating any log stream on Cloudwatch. How can I dig in this?

Comment: Can you explain where you made those two observations? i.e. `the indexing rate reached 10k` and `the logs on Kibana were not more that 1k`. Any screenshots that could be helpful?

Comment: @bot , do u have access to your elasticsearch nodes logs ? also how many replicas u have for your index?

Comment: @Val I looked at indexing rate metrics graph in AWS Elasticsearch Cluster health dashboard and log count by creating a Kibana dashboard to display one metrics showing log count.

Comment: @OpsterESNinja I had 5 shards and 5 replicas for each index. Excpet the cluster Error logs that can be setup from AWS ES on CloudWatch, I don't have access to any logs.

Comment: It's always best to check through queries in Dev Tools than trying to figure out numbers by creating visualizations and dashboards, since your time picker in Kibana might not select the correct time range for what you're currently observing...

Comment: @Val I created three different visualizations to validate this. I visualized number of logs (timebound) send by each service, send by each env, and send in total. Using the `/_count` API, I was able to find logs send by each index. Keeping all these factors in consideration I figured out that indexing rate might be incorrect. 

Also, I am not sure how I can run timebound query using `/_count` API. I can give it a try, if you are sure that this might be the right way to relate it to indexing rate.

Comment: I'm not saying it's the right way, all I'm saying is that you need to compare apples to apples. And for that you need to make sure that what you read from the AWS Elasticsearch Cluster health dashboard and what you do in Kibana are actually equivalent. If it was equivalent, you'd see the same numbers, I'd say.